# node.js process won't die on unhandled exception

Tags: node.js, exception, cluster-computing

Running the following server.js:

```
  cluster(app)
    .use(cluster.logger(path_to_logs))
    .use(cluster.stats())
    .use(cluster.pidfiles(path_to_pids))
    .use(cluster.cli())
    .use(cluster.repl(8888))
    .listen(3000);
```

it works as expected. However, let's throw in an unhandled exception like so:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
      throw new Error('User generated fault.');
   },5000);
```

Running the server with `$ node server.js, it starts and the exception is thrown after five seconds. Consequently the server is quit in what is seemingly the same as pressing ctrl+c.

However not quite. Because now trying to restart the server using `$ node server.js` I receive the following error:

```
Express server listening on port 3000

node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use
...
```

And running `$ ps aux | grep node` I can see that I still have two node processes running. Killing them allows me to start the server again. But since it was a manual kill, if I start the server again the same procedure starts over. 5 seconds pass, throw error, unable to restart.

This is a problem because with forever, it causes an infinite death cycle upon the first unhandled exception.

So my questions are:

1. Do you have any further ideas on why this might occur?
2. How can I listen for all exceptions and react by kill the process(es)
3. Is the above a bad approach?

---

Sorry for posting this on ServerFault aswell, but I realized this IS actually a code question.

Comment: You may want to use the native cluster module in 0.5.10 instead of the cluster module by learnboost

Answer (score 1):

About handling unhanded exceptions, you can use: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/process.html#event_uncaughtException_ .

About the process not quitting when an error is thrown: I do not know enough about cluster, but I believe to "scale" it creates child processes, and manages them, and does not die when a child dies. Taking a [basic look at the source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/blob/master/lib/master.js) it seems to be throwing a series of events, try seeing what events it is throwing and gather more information.

Comment: I seemingly solved the problem using unhandled exceptions mentioned by you @Nican as so: `process.addListener("uncaughtException", function (err) {
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGHUP');
});` However having a look at your comment about cluster I'm not sure this is a decent approach.